# ng-select [items] binding getting the options too many times

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I'm learning Angular, and tried to use NgSelect for the first time. And I noticed that if I use dropdownValues as [items] it is displaying in console "dropdownValues" each time mouse pointer is over any option in select, or each time I open and close the select control, etc. And just by moving the pointer fast over options I am getting 15-20 percent load on CPU, no matter if I use _dropdownValues or dropdownValues.
What is happening here? Why NgSelect needs to retrieve [items] each time I do something that should not be a reason for rerendering or retrieving [items] again. What can I do to optimize my code so that it wont load the CPU this much?

```
  <ng-select [items]="_dropdownValues" bindValue="value" [(ngModel)]="name"></ng-select>
  <ng-select [items]="dropdownValues" bindValue="value" [(ngModel)]="name"></ng-select>

  @Component({
    selector: 'testcomponent',
    templateUrl: './testcomponent.html'
  })
  export class TestComponent {
    _dropdownValues: DropdownOption[] = [];
    get dropdownValues() {
      console.log("dropdownValues");
      return this._dropdownValues;
    }
    constructor() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        this._dropdownValues.push({ value: i.toString(), label: "Test" + i });
      }
    }
  }

  export interface DropdownOption {
    value: string;
    label: string;
  }
```

Comment: That is because of the virtual scroll support on that, it asks for next 10 items

Comment: I tried turning it off explicitly specifying [virtualScroll]="false", same problem. And it seems virtualScroll is turned off by default, because I tried with 5000 items, and it's very slow if I don't specify [virtualScroll]="true"